# Non-recursive way to present $ p_{0}=0$, $p_{n+1}=(e+1)p_{n}+e$ for some $e>0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, recurrence-relations

Is there a non-recursive way to present this function:

$ p_{0}=0$

$p_{n+1}=(e+1)p_{n}+e$
for some $e>0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

Or at least some estimation from the top would satisfy me.

Comment: What about $p_n=\sum_{i=1}^n e^i(1+e)^{n-i}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $p_{n+1}+1=(\mathrm e+1)(p_n+1)$ for every $n\geqslant0$ and that $p_0+1=1$ hence $p_n=(\mathrm e+1)^n-1$ for every $n\geqslant0$. Thus, for example, $p_n\lt(\mathrm e+1)^n$ for every $n\geqslant0$.